# I can not use CURL on the Godaddy server

Tags: php, curl

Needing information about the goDaddy server error, I used CURL with the following commands in PHP.

I already tested it on another hosting server and it returned me successfully.

I'm using an API for sending messages in whatsapp, everything works: locally and on another server, except on goDaddy.

```
            $endpoint = "https://site...";


            $curl = curl_init($endpoint);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dados);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, true);

            $executa_api= curl_exec($curl);  
            curl_close($curl);
            $retorno= json_decode($executa_api);
```

do I need to authenticate something to use third-party API in godaddy?

**My phpinfo():**

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting? If it is a http 500 error then add this to the top of your script to get the actual error: `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set("display_errors", "on");`

Comment: no errors, just does not execute in server goDaddy

Comment: Define "does not execute".  If there's a problem there will be an error somewhere, if not then the code your showing us isn't being run in the first place and your problem is elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Also, please try echoing something just before and just after this code is run. This will help make sure that it is A) running in the first place and B) running to completion

Comment: but execute in server hostinger, hostgator and localhost.
so the problem is not in the code, but in the server.

Comment: Okay that means that it should satisfy condition A but what about condition B? Is it running to completion on GoDaddy?

Comment: When I use the API on localhost or another server, it has a return on json. when I use Godaddy, it returns NULL in all fields.

Comment: Json decode returns null whenever it encounters an error. In other words you are not getting valid Json Back from that API

Comment: [code]
$executa_api= curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$retorno= json_decode($executa_api);

$erro= $retorno->erro;
$sobre_o_erro= $retorno->sobre_o_erro;
$whatsapp_retorno= $retorno->whatsapp;
$mensagem_retorno= $retorno->mensagem;
$status= $retorno->status;
$idlog= $retorno->idlog;

var_dump($erro);
var_dump($sobre_o_erro);
var_dump($whatsapp_retorno);
var_dump($status);
var_dump($idlog);

Comment: Echo out $executa_api and tell us if it's empty or something else

Comment: **[You need to remove the two lines with `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/10/certainty-automated-cacert-pem-management-for-php-software)**. The values are wrong, and this could be causing your script to malfunction or be very insecure.

Comment: @Dharman but they are set to true, and thus kinda redundant and not the same as being set to false

Comment: @Scuzzy True, which makes this comment different from my usual message posted under curl questions, however `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` must be either 0 or 2(default), and it should never be 0/false or any other value. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` must be 0 or 1, and it should never be 0 either.

Comment: Sorry, I had personal problems.
returning, I gave $echo to executa_api and the same one just returned `bool(false)`, but executed in the localhost returning a correct jason of return of sending. I removed the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` lines, the same problem occurred.

Comment: Return Localhost: 
`object(stdClass)#1 (6) { ["erro"]=> string(3) "nao" ["sobre_o_erro"]=> string(12) "nao ha erros" ["idlog"]=> string(5) "00001" ["status"]=> string(11) "Processando" ["whatsapp"]=> string(13) "5584988116691" ["mensagem"]=> string(49) "Lembre-se do seu agendamento TesteServidorSalons." }`

Return goDaddy Server: `bool(false)`

Comment: @JuniorLira First try explicitly setting both `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` to `FALSE`. They can both cause issues if your server isn't properly configured. If that still doesn't work, tell us what `echo json_last_error_msg()` says. (make sure it's placed after `json_decode()`)

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST and CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE and no return yet.

Comment: in localhost, return success.

Comment: Must be a server error. i'll contact in server to resolve.

Comment: @JuniorLira It is worth asking them, but I doubt they will help you. Most of the time web hosts won't/can't help with code errors like this. One last thing you should try is adding `curl_error($curl)` after `curl_exec($curl);` but before `curl_close($curl);`. It is also possible the Godaddy server you got is/was hosting a spam service at some point and the API you are trying to contact is blocking your IP for abuse.

Comment: a similar error occurred when I tried to use SMTP in goDaddy, and it was only possible with 'jury-rigged'